# How to install texlive on headless Debian without the graphical tools?

Tags: debian

I'm using a headless Debian computer to work on LateX. If I try `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` I see a number of graphical programs that I don't need. I'd like to install all of texlive but without any of the graphical tools.

Is this possible?

Comment: A quick look over the package listing I see (Ubuntu 12.10TLTS) for `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` doesn't suggest any GUI packages I can spot. Could you specify your Debian version and which packages it's asking to add that you are not happy about? That said, this is borderline for us as one might argue this is a Debian issue (most 'TeX regulars' would do a vanilla install and ignore the Debian packaged version).

Comment: The TUG texlive installer also have a curses based install interface. That's what I usually use on my desktop

Comment: @daleif: That would be here: http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html ?

Comment: @SabreWolfy yes, download the non-windows installer,  and just run `install-tl` as is, no `-gui` option. It is fairly simple to use

Answer (score 1):

I do not install the official TL package from Ubuntu. I used:

```
wget https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/raw/master/install-tl-ubuntu && chmod +x ./install-tl-ubuntu
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu
```

Then you can later install a gui or not.

Comment: It is buying later grief to install non-official packages. They break with updates, you have to track updates yourself, integration to the system is a lot of work.

Comment: It is _not_ a pckage!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use your command line interface package management tools, e.g. `apt-get` for Debian. No GUI tools are part of (core) LaTeX.

Comment: I realize things may have changed in the past 7 years :) but when I run `apt-get install texlive-base` on an `ubuntu:jammy` Docker container, I see it install these suspiciously GUI-sounding packages: `x11-common, x11-utils, x11-server-utils, libgtk-3-0, libgtk-3-bin, libgtk-3-common`